# how to find the cycles using python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, plotly

I have battery voltage data i want to find the cycles in it is there any method in python to detect the cycles here I am pasting the link for the data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kJICTaMeuIzMnMNLPcetTFWK2YQO-hQx-Alx767jq3o/edit?usp=sharing
and here is my graph [image]

and i used plotly for plotting the graph

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
dfm=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Desktop\range\Battery Voltage.xlsx")

x=dfm["date_time"]
y=dfm["External Voltage"]
fig = px.line( x=x,y = y,
title = 'A simple line graph')
fig.show()
```

before i used the filter but i am loosing some data with that, is there any way to find the cycles in it

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible dataset?

Comment: I suspect that you don't mean local maxima and local minima according to the mathematical definition, since any point that is above its two neighbors is a local maximum, and it appears that the data goes up and down a lot, so many points, perhaps every point, would be local maxima and minima.

Comment: For the maxima, would you just like to identify points that are higher than every point within some window around it?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `scipy.signal.argrelextrema` for this case.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import numpy as np

data= pd.read_excel("Battery Voltage.xlsx")
plt.plot(data["date_time"],data["voltage"])
maxims=data.iloc[scipy.signal.argrelextrema(data["voltage"].values,comparator=np.greater_equal, order=200)[0]]
plt.scatter(maxims["date_time"], maxims["voltage"], c="yellow")
plt.show()
```

You could probably play around with the `order=Value` or the comparator. But maybe this is already what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: this code worked for me thank you so much